# attempting to determine fraction visible of image element (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to determine the fraction (as a decimal) that a particular image is in the viewport. Assume jQuery is available. Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/darrengates/4s7rk6xu/

In my code, I have a sequence of images with "figcaption" blocks beneath them, similar to what is shown in the fiddle.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        $('img').each(function() {

        var bounds = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var percentVisible = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (window.innerHeight - bounds.top) / bounds.height));

        $(this).next('figcaption').html(percentVisible);
    });
});
```

However, when I run this fiddle, it just shows "1" for all values, instead of the percent that the image is visible.

The idea is that when I start scrolling, the first image would go from "1" gradually down to "0" as it leaves the viewport. Then, the second image would go from about 0.2 (when I load the fiddle, the second cat is approximately 20% in view), to 1 and then gradually down to 0, etc.

I'm hoping to avoid jQuery plugins. I would also be fine with pure javascript solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this does the trick:

```
$.fn.pvisible = function() {
  var eTop = this.offset().top;
  var eBottom = eTop + this.height();
  var wTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var wBottom = wTop + $(window).height();
  var totalH = Math.max(eBottom, wBottom) - Math.min(eTop, wTop);
  var wComp = totalH - $(window).height();
  var eIn = this.height() - wComp;
  return (eIn <= 0 ? 0 : eIn / this.height() * 100);
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var percentVisible = $(this).pvisible().toFixed(2);
        $(this).next('figcaption').html(percentVisible);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> The [Darren Gates](http://Darren%20Gates) code is great. My code is longer but both have
>   the same result.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var viewport = window.screen;

  $('img').each(function (index) {

    var bounds = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var percentVisible = 0.0;

    // Determine which images are in the viewport
    if((bounds.top >= 0 && bounds.top <= viewport.height) || 
        (bounds.bottom >= 0 && bounds.bottom <= viewport.height) ||
        (bounds.top <= 0 && bounds.bottom >= viewport.height)
    ) {

        var imageArea = bounds.width * bounds.height;

        // The whole of the image is in the viewport
        if((bounds.top <= 0 && bounds.bottom >= viewport.height) ||
            (bounds.top >= 0 && bounds.bottom <= viewport.height)
         ) {
            percentVisible = 1.0;
        } 
        // The part of the image is in the viewport (out side from the top of the viewport)
        else if (bounds.top < 0 && bounds.bottom > 0 && bounds.bottom < viewport.height) {

            var visibleArea = bounds.bottom * bounds.width;
            percentVisible = visibleArea / imageArea;

        }
        // The part of the image is in the viewport (out side from the bottom of the viewport)
        else if (bounds.top > 0 && bounds.top < viewport.height && bounds.bottom > viewport.height) {

            var visibleArea = (viewport.height - bounds.top) * bounds.width;
            percentVisible = visibleArea / imageArea;

        }

    } else { // Image is not in the viewport
        percentVisible = 0;
    }

    percentVisible = percentVisible.toFixed(2);
    $(this).next('figcaption').html(percentVisible);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300">
<figcaption></figcaption>

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300">
<figcaption></figcaption>

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300">
<figcaption></figcaption>

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300">
<figcaption></figcaption>

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300">
<figcaption></figcaption>

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300">
<figcaption></figcaption>
```